# Make wkhtmltopdf to render text instead of curves

Tags: pdf, vector, fonts, rendering, wkhtmltopdf

When converting html into a PDF with `wkhtmltopdf` it seems that the text gets rendered to curves with the default options instead of getting a text-based PDF.

As a consequence it's not possible to select the text in the PDF (as it is a bunch of curves ressembling text) as well as having rendering problems (instead of delegating the rendering of the font to the PDF viewer).

## Additional info

There's much more context in here:

https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/2999

## Questions

- Q1) How can I tell wkhtmltopdf to render the document by placing text instead of converting text to curves?
- Q2) How can I ensure that wkhtmltopdf embeds the needed fonts inside the document just in case the destination machine does not have it?

Comment: What font do you use? I do not have any font set in my CSS and wkhtmltopdf renders text fine. I guess this might be related to the font you set.

Comment: But it does render "text that can be selected" or "curves that appear as text"?

Comment: The answer to your question is "Titillium Web" as stated in the link above. Specifically in this answer: https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/2999#issuecomment-392076321

Comment: Was there ever any resolution to this?  I've run into the same problem. I need real selectable text in PDF -- not curves.

Comment: No advances yet. I'm also still interested in it! See if anyone helps!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem. Converting the font file from .woff to .otf (as suggested [here](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/2022#issuecomment-571123945)) fixed it for me.